# Shipping method that changes shipping address magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, shipping-methods, shipping-address, free-shipping

I am trying to make a shipping method for free shipping that changes the shipping address when selected. this is what i have done so far but doesn't work where am i going wrong.

I have written this custom shipping method, its has both free and default shipping so which ever the user picks will excuse but the free shipping doesn't change the address what do i do?

```
<?php

class Cue_Customshippingmethod_Model_Demo
extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{



 protected $_code = 'cue_customshippingmethod';

  public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
  {
        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        /* @var $result Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result */

        $result->append($this->_getDefaultRate());


        if ($request->getFreeShipping()) {
            /**
             *  If the request has the free shipping flag,
             *  append a free shipping rate to the result.
             */

       $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
       $shippingAddress->setStreet(array('123 Main Street'))
               ->setCity('Los Angeles')
               ->setRegionId(12)
               ->setPostcode('90034')
               ->save();

            $result->append($this->_getFreeShippingRate());
        }

    return $result;
  }

  public function getAllowedMethods()
  {
    return array(
        'free_shipping' => 'Free Shipping',
        'cue_customshippingmethod' => $this->getConfigData('name'),
    );
  }

  protected function _getFreeShippingRate()
  {
    $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

    $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
    $rate->setMethod('free_shipping');
    //$rate->setMethodTitle('Free Shipping (3 - 5 days)');
    $rate->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
    $rate->setPrice(0);
    $rate->setCost(0);

    return $rate;
  }
   protected function _getDefaultRate() {
        $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        /* @var $rate Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method */

        $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
        /**
         * getConfigData(config_key) returns the configuration value for the
         * carriers/[carrier_code]/[config_key]
         */
        $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $rate->setMethod('standand');
        $rate->setMethodTitle('Standard');

        $rate->setPrice($this->getConfigData('price'));
        $rate->setCost(0);

        return $rate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
  {
        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        /* @var $result Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result */
        $result->append($this->_getDefaultRate());
        $result->append($this->_getFreeShippingRate());

    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $method = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();

         $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $ad1 = $shippingAddress->getStreet();
        $ad2 = $shippingAddress->setCity();
        $ad3  = $shippingAddress->setRegionId(12);
        $ad4  = $shippingAddress->setPostcode('90034');



        if ($method === 'cue_customshippingmethod_free_shipping') {
            /**
             *  If the request has the free shipping flag,
             *  append a free shipping rate to the result.
             */
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
       $shippingAddress->setStreet(array('123 Main Street'))
               ->setCity('Los Angeles')
               ->setRegionId(12)
               ->setPostcode('90034')
               ->save();

        }/*else{

         $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setStreet(array($ad1))
               ->setCity($ad2)
               ->setRegionId($ad3)
               ->setPostcode($ad4)
               ->save();

        }*/

    return $result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your code and I noticed a few issues.

**1. Custom Free Shipping Method not appended**

You have the append for $result->append($this->_getFreeShippingRate()); inside the conditional.

You need to remove this outside of the if statement so a user can select your shipping method.

You also need to update the "setMethodTitle" inside "_getFreeShippingRate" to  $rate->setMethodTitle("Free Shipping"); as the title when I setup your method was empty.

**2 Changing of Address**

Assuming that you want to change the shipping address when a user selects your "Free Shipping" method you to replace "if ($request->getFreeShipping()) {" with the following:

```
    $method = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();

    if ($method === 'cue_customshippingmethod_free_shipping') {
```

This will update the address to the LA address. You might also want to update the user's country aswell to the US.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Do you want to change the address when a user selects the custom "Free Shipping" method?

Comment: Yes I want to change the address when user selects free shipping (free means ship to store for pick up) n change back when user selects standard (ship to users address)

Comment: No problem. I will have an update for you in the next 24 hours.

Comment: Hi Colin, just wanted to end out if there s anything yet

Comment: I tried a few things but I was not able to do this using an observer. The issue is with trying to update the shipping address is already saved.  I was able to Mage:getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setStreet($street)->save() etc but this didn't work. You probably need to do this with JavaScript on the one page checkout.